# Countdown works on desktop and android browsers, but not iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, countdown

My code below works on desktop android phones and other operating systems. But Iphone does not work on devices.Where am I making a mistake?

```
var countdown = new Date("2019-09-09 06:35:10").getTime();
    var x = setInterval(function(){
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var distance = countdown - now;

        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor(distance % (1000 * 60 * 60) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor(distance % (1000 *60) / 1000);
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =  hours + " S. " + minutes + " Dk. " + seconds + " Sn. kaldı.";
    },1000)
```

Comment: No jQuery in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It happens on desktop Safari, too.

`new Date("2019-09-09 06:35:10")` results in `NaN` in Safari, "not a number".

`new Date("2019-09-09T06:35:10")` works, because JavaScript's date functions [expect an ISO 8601 compliant date format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). As you've discovered, *some* browsers accept a more varied range of date formats, but not all, so you should use the correct one.